# How to Automatically Save Sent Emails with Lotus Notes?

Tags: email, automation, lotus-notes

I am using Lotus Notes 8.  Every time I send an email it asks me if I want to save a copy of it in the Sent folder.  My answer to this is "Yes" every time.  How can I get it to automatically save the sent email every time without prompting me?  Thanks.

Comment: My condolences on having to use Notes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Notes 7

go to File --> Preferences --> User Preferences.  In the resulting dialog box, on the left hand side you should see a Mail tab.  If you expand that and click on General, then there is a drop down box called "Save mail that you send."  You can set it here to Always keep a copy.

### Notes 8 and 9

go to File -> Preferences -> Mail -> Sending and Receiving -> Sending group box. Then change "Save copies of messages that I send" from "Ask me" to "Always.

Comment: Yes, it was a little different, but you provided enough information for me to find it in Notes 8: File -> Preferences -> Mail -> Sending and Receiving -> Sending group box.  Then change "Save copies of messages that I send" from "Ask me" to "Always."

Comment: same for Notes 9